# It is possible in vscode to put the terminal on the right?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is it possible to move/open the terminal window to the right of the screen? That would allow me to optimize the editor spaces to work in more efficiently.

---

In vscode when we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> For example, open a terminal just below where the files are open,

[image]

Comment: Looks like it got added to a 6 month road map in March: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2806

Comment: @Bassie Thanks for the info I left here the Roadmap https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#workbench

Comment: Is this still an issue, and if so why? Otherwise please select an answer to show it has bee resolved. :-)

Answer (score 274):

Right Side Terminal Feature has been implemented.

---

Right click on the `Terminal` tab and select `Move Views to Side Panel` | `Move Panel Right`.

| Current Version (January 2024) | <Feb 2022 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Latest Version] | [image: Previous to Feb 2022] |

Comment: All the 4 panes are moved, not only the terminal pane.

Comment: You cannot do that as of 4.02.2022 with the new "Side panel" view option introduced in update 1.64.0

Comment: This was removed in latest update. Where is it now? Edit: found it, since January 2022 release you have to "Show Side Panel" and then drag the Terminal window into the Side Panel.

Comment: To undo this the only way I found is to use `>View: Move Secondary Side Bar Views to Panel` in the command pallet.

Comment: Completely life changing

Answer (score 25):

***View*** > ***Appearance*** > ***Toggle Panel Position***, which hides the panel, does the trick for me.

It also saves the state so that next time it opens the Terminal to the right.

Comment: Also possibly `view -> appearance -> panel position -> (bottom | left | right)` in newer versions

Answer (score 15):

Another option, offered with VSCode 1.58 (June 2021):

By creating a terminal in the editor aera itself, you can put said terminal wherever you want!

> ### [Integrated Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/235846643c80030148ce8e1080a9d59142337dcf/release-notes/v1_58.md#integrated-terminal)
>
> #### Terminals in the editor area
>
> Terminals can now be created in or moved to the editor area, enabling a multi-dimensional grid layout that persists and remains visible regardless of panel state.
>
> Create terminals via the **`Create Terminal in Editor Area`** command.
>
> Move a terminal from the panel to the editor by dragging and dropping from the tabs list, running Move Terminal into Editor Area with a terminal focused, or selecting the context menu action.
>
> [image: 4 terminals in the editor area are laid out in a 2 by 2 grid]
>
> #### Canvas renderer
>
> In a prior iteration, we removed the `terminal.integrated.rendererType` setting in favor of `terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration` when we enabled the WebGL renderer by default.
>
> Some architectures have improved terminal performance when using the canvas renderer.
>
> To use the canvas renderer, set `terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration` to `canvas`.
>
> #### New terminal settings
>
> - Set `terminal.integrated.defaultLocation` to `editor` to direct newly created terminals to the editor area.
> - **Set `terminal.integrated.showLinkHover` to `false` to disable link hovers in the terminal.**
>   This can be useful if you find them distracting, for example.

Comment: @eduncan911 Wait 1.59: you will be able to switch terminal across... windows! July 2021: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/f0d72b996b579d3cebb44f9746c9af8a776861b0/release-notes/v1_59.md#drag-and-drop-terminals-across-windows

Comment: I don't think I want to *cross the streams* like that.

Answer (score 14):

As of the end of 2017, there is a button to do that: click on icon on the top right "Move to right" (if you don't see it, resize you windows).

---

Edit 2020: This answer is no longer correct for the new version, see @ΩmegaMan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768672/285795) (in brief: right click on the terminal bar)

Comment: Right click on terminal bar worked fine for me (late 2021).

Answer (score 8):

As of v1.64:

You can click the "Layout Control" and choose `Show Side Panel`
or the menu `View/Appearance/Show Side Panel`

[image: Side Panel Terminal]

and then you can drag various views into like the Terminal/Debug/Outline/SCM views.

[image: Terminal in Side Panel demo]

So you will be able to have the Panel remain on the bottom for other content and a Side Bar on the left/right and a Side Panel on the opposite side.

---

And with v1.64.2 you can use the command:

`View: Move Panel Right` or Left or Bottom

which will move the Panel to the right with the optional Side Panel to its right.  The terminal can be in any one of those Panels, by dragging it for example.

Side Bar | Editors | Panel | Side Panel

See a couple more demos at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330

Answer (score 7):

From the navbar: View>Appearance>Panel Position> Right

Answer (score 3):

VS Code 2022 Version 1.67.0

From the navbar: View>Appearance>Panel Position> Right

Answer (score 2):

**Latest answer as per the November 2021.**

> View => Appearance => Move Side Bar Right:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can also toggle the position of the *Panel* using vanilla `when` clause.

[VS Code docs - when clause](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts)

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+/",
    "command": "workbench.action.positionPanelRight",
    "when": "panelPosition == 'bottom'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+/",
    "command": "workbench.action.positionPanelBottom",
    "when": "panelPosition == 'right'"
  },
```

Helps to 'minimize' terminal to the bottom when needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this change permanent, add this line to your `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"
```