# Can we combine grid layout and terminal panel in vscode?

Tags: layout, visual-studio-code

There is the [grid layout](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_grid-editor-layout) in vs-code, and there is the [terminal panel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal). Is there a way to combine both?

Lets say I want this :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |         something         |
|                                |            here           |
|          editor here           |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |---------------------------|
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |          terminal         |
|                                |            here           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
|                                |                           |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877697/it-is-possible-in-vscode-to-put-the-terminal-on-the-right) we can put the terminal on the right, but I do not know if we can put it in the bottom of the right column. It works with other panel though, like editor.

Comment: I would really love to see this feature. Like Grid Mode for terminals 2x2, 2x3, etc.

Comment: anyone know if there's been any action on this? i've seen some discussion in github issues, but still can't seem to get this layout! sad </3

Answer (score 0):

To my best understanding, you cannot put the whole terminal panel (thinking of the combined: problems, output, debug console, terminal, ... group) in the grid layout.
However, you can put **individual terminal shells** into the editor and they will behave like opened files, able to be moved between editor panes.

After you have opened the terminal panel, you can drag and drop the shell's name (located just left of the little + sign where you can create a new terminal. It will have a name like `bash` or any other shell you are using) into the editor.

To make it easier, there is a setting for `terminal.integrated.defaultLocation` where you can specify the value to be `editor`. You split the editor panel as you see fit and then press workbench.action.terminal.new (default keycode is Ctrl+`) and you terminal will appear in the selected grid section.