# In VScode how to split panels to have terminal and editor next to each other

Tags: layout, visual-studio-code

I am trying to split my VScode windows to look something like the image below. It's easy enough to split the terminal and split the editor but I'm not sure if its possible to obtain something like the layout below. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now appears to be possible with the `Create Terminal in Editor Area` command. It works for me:

[image]

See the description on this feature from vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/235846643c80030148ce8e1080a9d59142337dcf/release-notes/v1_58.md#integrated-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the layout that are looking for, but VS Code now supports terminal on the right side.

Right click on the `Terminal` tab and select `Move Panel Right`.

You can follow the steps as shown in below screenshot:
[open-terminal-in-right-hand-side-pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yihh3.png)

You can also refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768672

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29878862)

Comment: Thanks @NadPat for the suggestion, I have updated my answer.

Comment: This answer will not work the way the OP is asking for.